# htmlentities Best Practice Questions On Php

Tags: php, url, html-entities

Should you have urlencode() inside htmlentities() or outside it in PHP ?

About Query Strings in URL. Can the first part be inside htmlentities() or only last part ? Maybe both ?

If URL looks like this:
Url: site.com/?url=go.com

First part:
url=

Last part:
go.com

Whatabout directly placing URLs inside htmlentities() ? Or should you place the URL in a variable and then place that variable inside the htmlentities() ?

Do show us some examples how you do it yourselves.

Cheers.

I coded 4 different ways that work but suspect not all of them valid. Need you to point out the incorrect or bad practice examples from below.

EXAMPLE 1

```
<?php
//EXAMPLE 1: 
//urlencode() outside htmlentities().
//Url in a Variable. Then that Var is inside htmlentities().
//htmlentities() exclude URL query strings.

$selfpage = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
echo 'Page: ';
if($page>$total_pages)
{
    echo '<a href="' .htmlentities("$selfpage") .'?tbl=' .urlencode("$tbl") .'&col=' .urlencode("$col") .'&search=' .urlencode("$search") .'&page=' .$total_pages .'"><font size="8"><b>' .$total_pages .'</b></a></font>';
}
else
{
    while($i<=$total_pages)
    {
        if($i==$page)
        {
            echo '<a href="' .htmlentities($selfpage) .'?tbl=' .urlencode($tbl) .'&col=' .urlencode($col) .'&search=' .urlencode($search) .'&page=' .$i .'"><font size="8"><b>' .$i .'</b></a></font>';
        }
        else
        {
            echo '<a href="' .htmlentities($selfpage) .'?tbl=' .urlencode($tbl) .'&col=' .urlencode($col) .'&search=' .urlencode($search) .'&page=' .$i .'"><font size="4">' .$i .'</a></font>';
        }
        $i++;
    }
}
echo '<br>';
echo '<br>';
?>
```

EXAMPLE 2

```
<?php
//EXAMPLE 2:
//urlencode() outside htmlentities().
//Url directly inserted inside htmlentities().
//htmlentities() exclude URL query strings.

echo 'Page: ';
if($page>$total_pages)
{
    echo '<a href="' .htmlentities("http://www.ydomain.com/search/pagination.php") .'?tbl=' .urlencode("$tbl") .'&col=' .urlencode("$col") .'&search=' .urlencode("$search") .'&page=' .urlencode($total_pages) .'"><font size="8"><b>' .$total_pages .'</b></a></font>';
}
else
{
    $i = 1;
    while($i<=$total_pages)
    {
        if($i==$page)
        {
            echo '<a href="' .htmlentities("http://www.ydomain.com/search/pagination.php") .'?tbl=' .urlencode($tbl) .'&col=' .urlencode($col) .'&search=' .urlencode($search) .'&page=' .$i .'"><font size="8"><b>' .urlencode($i) .'</b></a></font>';
        }
        else
        {
            echo '<a href="' .htmlentities("http://www.ydomain.com/search/pagination.php") .'?tbl=' .urlencode($tbl) .'&col=' .urlencode($col) .'&search=' .urlencode($search) .'&page=' .$i .'"><font size="4">' .urlencode($i) .'</a></font>';
        }
        $i++;
    }
}
echo '<br>';
echo '<br>';
?>
```

EXAMPLE 3

```
<?php
//EXAMPLE 3:
//urlencode() inside htmlentities().
//Url in a Variable. Then that Var is inside htmlentities().
//htmlentities() include both query strings and non-query string parts of URL.

echo 'Page: ';
if($page>$total_pages)
{
    $final_page = 'http://www.ydomain.com/search/pagination.php' .'?tbl=' .urlencode("$tbl") .'&col=' .urlencode("$col") .'&search=' .urlencode("$search") .'&page=' .urlencode($total_pages);
    echo '<a href="' .htmlentities("$final_page") .'"><font size="8"><b>' .$total_pages .'</b></a></font>';
}
else
{
    $i = 1;
    while($i<=$total_pages)
    {
        $self_page = 'http://www.ydomain.com/search/pagination.php' .'?tbl=' .urlencode("$tbl") .'&col=' .urlencode("$col") .'&search=' .urlencode("$search") .'&page=' .urlencode($i);
        if($i==$page)
        {
            echo '<a href="' .htmlentities("$self_page") .'"><font size="8">' .$i .'</a></font>';
        }
        else
        {
            echo '<a href="' .htmlentities("$self_page") .'"><font size="4">' .$i .'</a></font>';
        }
        $i++;
    }
}
?>
```

EXAMPLE 4

```
<?php
//EXAMPLE 4:
//urlencode() inside htmlentities().
//htmlentities() include only query strings and non-query string parts of URL excluded from htmlentities().

$self_page = "http://www.ydomain.com/search/pagination.php";
echo 'Page: ';
if($page>$total_pages)
{
    $final_page_query_string = '?tbl=' .urlencode("$tbl") .'&col=' .urlencode("$col") .'&search=' .urlencode("$search") .'&page=' .urlencode("$total_pages");
    echo '<a href="' ."$self_page" .htmlentities("$final_page_query_string") .'"><font size="8"><b>' .$total_pages .'</b></a></font>';
}
else
{
    $i = 1;
    while($i<=$total_pages)
    {
        if($i==$page)
        {
            $query_string = '?tbl=' .urlencode("$tbl") .'&col=' .urlencode("$col") .'&search=' .urlencode("$search") .'&page=' .urlencode("$i");
            echo '<a href="' ."$self_page" .htmlentities("$query_string") .'"><font size="8"><b>' .$i .'</b></a></font>';
        }
        else
        {
            $query_string = '?tbl=' .urlencode("$tbl") .'&col=' .urlencode("$col") .'&search=' .urlencode("$search") .'&page=' .urlencode("$i");
            echo '<a href="' ."$self_page" .htmlentities("$query_string") .'"><font size="4">' .$i .'</a></font>';
        }
        $i++;
    }
}

?>
```

Comment: The `<font>` tag was used in HTML 4 to specify the font face, font size, and color of text. It is no longer supported in HTML5.

Comment: Using `htmlentities` encodes the string, so it can actually break the url completely. If you are going to use it, it should just be on each individual value in the query string.

Comment: With all of that said, why not just try each solution and see if it works, considering you've already written them?

Comment: @GrumpyCrouton,All the examples work fine in the browser. But am told I don't need to use htmlentities() in any of these 4 examples but urlencode() only. I wanted confirmation from this forum.Anyway,what should I use as substitute to the font tag in html 5?

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_font.asp

Comment: For URLs just use `urlencode`.  If your displaying on an HTML page use `htmlentities`.

Comment: @AbracaDaver, If I am displaying links on a page, like Google search result page, then which one I use ?

Comment: @GrumpyCrouton,Thanks.